# Boot repair: “GRUB is still present. Please try again ” message is displayed while reparing the boot with ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, boot-repair

I have tried running boot-repair on my laptop and am receiving the message "GRUB is still present. Please try again."

Below is the URL to paste from boot-repair

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Tght56pCRP/

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You need to mount LVM before running Boot-Repair. It looks like a normal LVM install on gpt partitioned drive in UEFI boot mode, but you have an old Windows boot loader in gpt's protective MBR. That should not matter as long as you do not try to BIOS/Legacy boot. What brand/model system? Grub does not use boot flag, Windows does in BIOS mode, so some systems want a boot flag. The FAT32 partition as ESP - efi system partition usually has both esp, boot flags.

Answer (score -1):

you should run gparted and format the boot drive and have the boot-repair reinstall grub. you can backup the drive if you are afraid of losing any info there. Mostly you got nothing to worry about though, I've done it many times and grub can be installed again with boot-repair on that drive.

Note: you may want to go to gparted again after to set the boot flag for the boot drive. you can do it after you format or before you start as well just as an extra step. can't hurt to check it after because sometimes the flag is not added and the system does not boot just because of that even though the repair is done.